# change value of a variable without a function using a tkinter button

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am new to programming and I want to know If there is any way to change the value of a variable with a Tkinter button out calling a function.
As I have to give a function as `command` to change the value of any variable.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

a = 1


def test():
    global a
    a = 2
    return


root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Click", command=test)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But I want to know if there is a way to do it directly without using any function.

Something that might look like this:

```
command = (a = 2)
```

Comment: nope, you have to use a function, but why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @TijmenThankyou Sir, For your quick response, I just wanted to know if it was possible as there is a chance of running into errors if one has to change the value of more than one variable.

Comment: What kind of errors, Maybe I can help?

Comment: @Tijmen No thanks, I just meant "There is a Chance" of running into errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a function, otherwise it won't work.