# How do I change value of a variable using a tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a variable for example: x = 1. And I want to change it to x = 2 using a tkinter button.

I tried:

```
b1 = Button(root,bg = "black",fg = "white",text = "idk",command = (x=2))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593277/change-value-of-a-variable-without-a-function-using-a-tkinter-button

Answer (score 2):

U can call a function on command to set your global variable

```
x=3
b1 = Button(root,bg = "black",fg = "white",text = "idk",command = vall)

def vall():
    global x
    x=2
```